# Employer is 1099ing me for RENT for live-on-site work

Tags: united-states, taxes, self-employment, form-1099

We were hired by a company for a contract position.  We were to receive a small wage and housing in exchange for work.  We got a 1099 at the end of the year that claims that we received about $7000 more for 4 months pay than we actually received.  I assume they are attempting to justify the RENT of this property as income.  Between you and me, this was an OFFICE space which we bought a bed into so we had somewhere to sleep, this was NOT a home by any stretch of the imagination.

What do I do?  We never had anything in writing and I filled out a W-4 with him not a W-9.  I feel he cannot just come up with an arbitrary dollar amount for "Rent".

***EDIT We were REQUIRED by the employer to stay on site as a condition of employment

Comment: Who is "we"? Is the $7000 for all of you or each of you? $1750/mo for a bed is steep.

Answer (score 4):

Housing in exchange for work is taxable income except under very particular circumstances, usually those in which the residency in housing is a **requirement** for the work.

If living in the particular location is a requirement for the work, they may still 1099 you (and may be required to do so) the "fair market" value of the rent. You *may* be eligible for an exemption for that amount, again, depending on very specific circumstances.

You could consult a tax attorney, but I strongly suspect that if there is any ambiguity about whether or not this is taxable, it **is** a taxable fringe benefit.

[IRS Non-taxable Fringe Benefits](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p15b/ar02.html#en_US_2014_publink1000193699) stipulates the following test for whether an employer needs to declare the housing as taxable income (must meet all three):

> It is furnished on your business premises.
>
> It is furnished for your convenience.
>
> The employee must accept it as a condition of employment.

**EDIT:** In response to your new detail that you were required to live on site, you simply need to claim this as an exemption in your tax return as non-taxable wages. The employer needs to quantify the value exchanged, and you need to record having received it, regardless of whether or not it is tax-exempt.

Comment: "Your convenience" here refers to the business's convenience, not the employee's.

Comment: Yes, all of these tests are for whether **the employer** must presume the amount taxable.

Comment: The job DID require us to live on site

Comment: @Cade Then you should classify it on your return as a non-taxable fringe benefit. The Employer is still going to record the expense...

Comment: My accountant is saying that because he 1099'ed me instead of W-2'ed me I cannot claim it as a fringe benefit since I was not an employee